# how to separate key and value separately from a dictionary object

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a class which is the return type for my web API.

the class:

```
public class abc
{
   public string field1{ get; set; }

   public Dictionary<string, char> field2{ get; set; }      
}
```

My query is when i return the class object from the API. The structure should be in the below format for the dictionary object:

```
[{
  “field1” : “D123456XYZ”,
// for field2 in the below format
  [{ “key”: “123”
      “value”: “y”
    },
    { “key”: "456"
      “value”: “n”
    },
    { “key”: “789”
      “value”: “y”
    }

}]
```

how can it be done?

Comment: Please post your controller/action, and the output you get right now with the code you are using. So we both know what went wrong and have a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Json.Net library to do this. You can construct a new `JObject` and the manually set its properties based on the items in the dictionary.

```
foreach ( var pair in field2 )
{
     var item = new JObject();
     item[ pair.Key ] = pair.Value;
}
```

Alternatively, you could create a custom converter and just add an attribute to the property so that this happens automatically.

```
public class ObjectDictionaryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) ||
                TypeImplementsGenericInterface(objectType, typeof(IDictionary<,>)));
    }

    private static bool TypeImplementsGenericInterface(Type concreteType, Type interfaceType)
    {
        return concreteType.GetInterfaces()
                .Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == interfaceType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dictionary = (IDictionary)value;
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach ( var key in dictionary.Keys)
        {
            var keysValue = dictionary[key];
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName(key.ToString());
            writer.WriteValue(keysValue);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You then apply this custom converter like this:

```
public class abc
{
    public string field1 { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectDictionaryConverter))]
    public Dictionary<string, char> field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain with example

Comment: I have added one partial example, I will expand it if necessary